# Webapi 2 controllers on 2 projects

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have a webapi2 C# projects on which I have all the controllers in a controllers folder.
I now have some functionality that I want to add but I want to put it on a different visual studio project that will have its own controllers (and models and views) folder. Is this possible so that I can create some kind of module that will be loaded by webapi2?

Comment: 1) Put all the controllers in the web project, and have those controllers call out to different services (that live in another project). Little, to no logic (other than exception handling/logging) should be in your controllers. They should just call out to another class to do the work. 
2) Create two separate applications under iis, and build a new api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Web Api relies on the [IHttpControllerSelector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.dispatcher.ihttpcontrollerselector(v=vs.118).aspx) for choosing the api controller for handling a request, of which has a default implementation which relies on [IAssembliesResolver](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.dispatcher.iassembliesresolver(v=vs.118).aspx) for resolving the assemblies to search for the api controllers.

In the least minimum change, you can replace this assembly resolver with a custom implementation which will load other libraries for you.

A very naive example might look like the following:

```
public class CustomAssemblyResolver : IAssembliesResolver
{
    public List<string> PluginNames { get; set; }

    public CustomAssemblyResolver()
    {
        PluginNames = new List<string>();

        //Add the custom libraries here
        PluginNames.Add("Your_Second_Library");
    }

    public ICollection<Assembly> GetAssemblies()
    {
        var asms = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().ToList();
        foreach (var name in PluginNames)
        {

            var asmPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/"), name + ".dll");
            try
            {
                var asm= System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(asmPath);
                if(!asms.Contains(asm))
                    asms.Add(asm);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

            }
        }
        return asms;
    }
}
```

You can then replace the default resolver with this code

```
config.Services.Replace(typeof(IAssembliesResolver), new CustomAssemblyResolver());
```

inside your `Register` method of `WebApiConfig` class.

Then, copy all your additional libraries with controller classes to the bin directory and you are done.

If you need even further customization for controller selection, you can go for custom implementation of `IHttpControllerSelector` and replace the existing implementation in a similar fashion.

Answer (score -1):

You can create the functionality in a library project, and then reference that project to the your webapi2 and your other visual studio project. Basically you will have three solutions; two webapi solutions and one library solution. The library solution will contain the required logic needed for the two webapi solutions.

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't have a need for controllers in two projects.

If the controllers are for COMPLETELY different business domains, make two api's in IIS w/ two solutions.

If they are similar, create all of your controllers in the web project. Then have these controllers call out to separate application services.

```
public CustomerAccountsController : ApiController
{
    private CustomerAccountService _customerAccountService; // lives in application layer project
    public CustomerAccountsController() 
    { 
        // di stuff 
    }

    public HttpResponseMessage PutCancelAccount( int accountId )
    {
       // exception handling + logging
       _customerAccountService.CancelAccount(accountId);

      // return status code if success, or if an exception
    }
}

public OrderController : ApiController
{
    private OrderService _orderService; // lives in application layer project
    public OrderController()
    { //di stuff
    }

    public HttpResponseMessage PostCreateOrder(CreateOrderRequest createOrderRequest) 
    {
        // exception handling + logging
        _orderService.TakeOrder(createOrderRequest);

        // return status code if success, or if an exception
    }
}
```

So, most of your logic should hide behind application layer services, and these services should have methods that map 1-1 to use cases. If your business domain for these two applications are completely different, just create two separate solutions and two separate IIS applications/api's

Comment: You could also consider Area's. Web Api has that too, right?

Answer (score -1):

No, it is not possible. The maximum you can do is create a class library that will compile as a DLL, then reference that DLL in your WebApi. Otherwise, you will be obliged to either put everything in the same application (WebApi) or create two different WebApi applications.

Answer (score -1):

Depending on your needs...

My advise, just put the 2 controllers on a single project and create a helper/service folder/class in your other project and call those services whenever you need.

This is not really the answer to your question but I believe this will help. Normally we create a solution using this folder structure, I hope this helps:

```
MyTeamSolution
    - MyTeam.Core   = Class libraries
        > Models
            > Model1.cs
            > Model2.cs 
            > Model3.cs
        > Interface
            > ISomeInterface.cs
        > Helpers
            > HelperClass.cs

    - MyTeam.Api    = webapi project
        > Model1Controller.cs
        > Model2Controller.cs
        > Model3Controller.cs
    - MyTeam.Web    = mvc project
        > Controllers
        > Models
        > Views
        > etc. 
    - MyTeam.Sql    = Class libraries
        > MyTeamDbContext.cs
```